# Compensation for delayed baggage on international United flight

Tags: air-travel, luggage, united-airlines, compensation, disputes

My bag on an international flight with United Airlines was delayed. The bag got delivered at its destination about 36 hours after I arrived. During that time, not only did I not have clothes to change or toiletry items, but I was unable to purchase anything to replace some of those items as this was over a long weekend in Europe, when almost all the stores are closed.

Am I entitled to a compensation from United Airlines? If I am, for how much, and what is the best way to claim for that compensation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According the [official site](http://www.united.com/page/article/0,6867,1037,00.html):

> If your bags do not arrive at your destination, report this to the United baggage agents in the claim area/office before you leave the airport. It is important to do so as soon as possible so we may obtain information pertinent to locating your luggage. **Please note that all lost, damaged or delayed property must be reported to United within 24 hours**.
>
> In addition, a written claim giving full description and value of the missing property must be submitted to United within 45 days of the occurrence. If your bag was misplaced, we will make every reasonable effort to return your checked baggage within 24 hours in the United States.

I think you are interested in this section:

> If your bag has been located and returned to you, and you still wish to request reimbursement of related expenses, send your request in writing, within 45 days of the occurrence, to the following address. Please include a copy of your ticket receipt, any baggage claim checks, a copy of your delayed baggage report, and any itemized purchase receipts pertinent to your claim.
>
> **United Airlines
>
> Central Baggage Services - HDQLZ
>
> P.O. Box 66140
>
> Chicago, IL 60666-0140**

Answer (score 2):

From my experience I can tell you that once a lady's luggage got delayed and she had a suit in her suitcase which she needed the next morning for some job thing. She could then buy a new suit and send the bill to the luggage handling company.

So as far as it is for things you really need the next day(or 2), you can buy them and send the receipts to the company. I don't know how much they will pay you. You could ask them for your rights as passenger (they should give/send/tell you when you ask) and see if it says anything about that.

Comment: I had my baggage delayed when traveling by Srilankan Airlines and they reimbursed the cost of Taxi from my home to the airport also.

Comment: United paid for half of a dress shirt, underwear, and socks for a 48-hour delay. Swissair (the old one) promised me a full repayment on some casual clothes but had not paid me back when they went bankrupt. I thought my recovery as an unsecured creditor was not worth pursuing.