# Compensation for baggage delay (Air Mauritius)

Tags: uk, luggage, compensation, mauritius

I flew back from Mauritius to London last week and they left behind **ALL 4** baggage.
We got 2 back after 2 days and the last 2 yesterday. On top of the delay, the content was wet.

Can I claim any compensation? What does the law say?

Comment: Have you read https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1330/compensation-for-delayed-baggage-on-international-united-flight?rq=1 ?

Comment: @MadHatter that's specific for United Airlines

Comment: Where did you fly back to? We can't tell you what the law says if we don't know which laws apply.

Comment: @ChrisH edited the question to add the destination (London)

Comment: Have you checked what your travel insurance covers? Or your home insurance may have eg personal possessions cover that might be of use?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.caa.co.uk/Passengers/Resolving-Travel-Problems/Lost-delayed-or-damaged-baggage/

"...If your bag is delayed **on your return home**, airlines may consider that your losses were less as you had clothes and other essentials available to you....."

(edit for this link) And from [Air Mauritius](https://www.airmauritius.com/conditions-of-carriage/liability-for-damage):

"....With respect to delay, carrier shall be under no liability except as provided in these conditions of carriage...."

You say that you flew back, so I assume you are home with all necessities (minus some clothing and toiletries), so not real damage (imo).

It's all a question of how much are you willing to spend on this issue in regards to what you would/could gain.

I would contact the airline (and/or airport) and make a claim and wait it out; if you get something good, if not, count yourself luck to have all your belonging back.

Comment: What about the mold in the luggage? Is it not considered a damage?

Comment: @algiogia Is it so mouldy that washing is ineffective?

Comment: Note also in the conditions of carriage: "*Carrier shall be liable for damage to a passenger or his checked baggage only if such damage has been caused by the negligence of Carrier"* and "*our liability in the case of Damage to Checked Baggage shall be limited to USD 20 per kilo for a maximum of 20 Kgs"*.  First you'd have to prove negligence (not mere error) on their part, then you can only claim up to $400 (about £300).  It's not worth it, which is why many people have travel insurance to cover this sort of thing.

Comment: @MadHatter Thanks. I suppose I'll have to let go then.